# Definied Anonymous class in rspec won't respond to new

Tags: ruby, rspec, anonymous-class

so I have the following anonymous class definition:

```
  let!(:fake_class) do
    Class.new(Integer) do
      def initialize(value)
        @value = value
      end

      def ==(other)
        @value == other
      end

      def coerce(other)
        [@value, other]
      end

      def to_s
        @value.to_s
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I do:

```
fake_class.new 4
```

I just get `undefined method 'new' for #<Class:0x00007fc065377c88>`

I've tried doing

```
define_method :initialize do |value|
  @value = value
end
```

no difference

the only way it responds to new is if I do

```
class << self
  def new(value)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

but that obviously won' work as I need it to act like a real class.

Why do I see lots of tutorials using `intialize` and it working as expected yet it doesn't seem to work for me? Is it becuase i'm defining it in rspec or somthing?

Comment: Why do you subclass `Integer` in the first place? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is nothing to do with `rspec`, nor anonymous classes.

The problem is that in ruby, **you cannot subclass `Integer`***.

Ruby stores small `Integer`s (formerly known as `Fixnum`s) as immediate values, using some of the low bits of the word to tag it as such, instead of a pointer to an object on the heap. Because of that, you can't add methods to a single "instance" of `Integer`, and you can't subclass it.

If you really want an "Integer-like" class, you could construct a workaround with a  class that has an integer instance variable, and forward method calls appropriately:

```
class FakeInteger
  def initialize(integer)
    @integer = integer
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    ret = @integer.send(name, *args, &blk)
    ret.is_a?(Numeric) ? FakeInteger.new(ret) : ret
  end
end
```

* *Technically* you can, but since you cannot instantiate any objects from it, it's pretty useless :)

Comment: E.g. use delegator pattern.

Comment: There's a good chance OP doesn't *really* want to subclass `Integer` in the first place :) My guess is that their code would work fine with just `Class.new`, instead of `Class.new(Integer)` (but I'd need more context to know!)

Comment: _"you cannot subclass Integer"_ – you can, but it's pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct but `Integer` does not respond to `.new` and so your child class will also not respond to `.new`.

```
irb(main):001:0> Integer.new
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Integer:Class)
```

When you call `Integer(123)` you actually call a global function defined here:
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_1/object.c#L3987
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_1/object.c#L3178

Comment: This is the [mcve] that should really have been provided by OP :)

Comment: _"Integer is actually a global function"_ – no, `Integer` is _also_ a global function: [`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer). But that has nothing to do with the way `new` or `allocate` work (or are prevented to work).

Comment: Yes, your're right it's a class and a global function.